# How to sum all of values from specific key in object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Let's say I have a array that contains a multiple object like:

```
var arr = [{ 'credit': 1, 'trash': null }, { 'credit': 2, 'trash': null}]
```

I want to get a sum of all `credit` value from `arr` array. so expected sum value is 3. so I used this code:

`arr.reduce((obj, total) => obj.credit + total)`

but when I run this, I get `"1[object Object]"` which is really weird.

Ps: I'm trying to implement this using ES6 not ES5

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @KevinB I used reduce in the code and result came out wrong. details in the post

Comment: Right, read the examples. you're doing something backwards.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Two problems: your `total` and `obj` arguments are backwards, and you need to provide something to initialize the `total` variable (that's the `,0` part)

```
arr.reduce((total, obj) => obj.credit + total,0)
// 3
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.forEach()` here:

```js
var arr = [{ 'credit': 1, 'trash': null }, { 'credit': 2, 'trash': null}];

var total = 0;
arr.forEach(item => {
    total += item.credit;
});
  
console.log(total);
```