# javascript sum value by key from array of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, sum

I want to sum an object value by key.
I have an array of arrays of objects.

Here:
[  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5pVE.png): [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550691/how-to-sum-all-of-values-from-specific-key-in-object][1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550691/how-to-sum-all-of-values-from-specific-key-in-object%5D%5B1%5D)

I found this:

```js
var arr = [{ 'credit': 1, 'trash': null }, { 'credit': 2, 'trash': null}];
console.log(arr.reduce((total, obj) => obj.credit + total,0));
// 3
```

I have multiple arrays of objects, thus:

```js
var arr2 = [ [{ 'credit': 1, 'trash': null }, { 'credit': 2, 'trash': null}],
            [{ 'credit': 3, 'trash': null }, { 'credit': 3, 'trash': null}]
          ];

for (var i=0; i<arr2.length; i++) {
    console.log( arr2[i].reduce((total, arr2[i]) => arr2[i].credit + total,0))  ;
}
```

When trying to access a specific array I get this error message from Google Chrome "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target".

The editor I am using, Sublime, highlights a syntax error.
[image: Sublime editor highlights syntax error]

I don't know how to fix it. I have googled without success.

I want to get the total for each iteration of the loop.
In the example given, that would :
3
then
6

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flatten the array, then `.reduce` to sum.

```js
var arr2 = [ [{ 'credit': 1, 'trash': null }, { 'credit': 2, 'trash': null}],
            [{ 'credit': 3, 'trash': null }, { 'credit': 3, 'trash': null}]
          ];

console.log(arr2.flat().reduce((total, obj) => obj.credit + total,0));
```

If you don't want to flatten, you'll have to use a nested `.reduce` for the inner arrays too.

```js
var arr2 = [ [{ 'credit': 1, 'trash': null }, { 'credit': 2, 'trash': null}],
            [{ 'credit': 3, 'trash': null }, { 'credit': 3, 'trash': null}]
          ];

console.log(
  arr2.reduce(
    (total, subarr) => total + subarr.reduce(
      (a, { credit }) => a + credit,
      0
    ),
    0
  )
);
```

If you don't care about the full total but only about each subarray's total, then just perform the simple `.reduce` for every element of the array.

```js
var arr2 = [ [{ 'credit': 1, 'trash': null }, { 'credit': 2, 'trash': null}],
            [{ 'credit': 3, 'trash': null }, { 'credit': 3, 'trash': null}]
          ];

for (const subarr of arr2) {
  console.log(subarr.reduce((total, obj) => obj.credit + total,0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I want to get the total for each iteration of the loop.
In the example given, that would :
3
then
6

I have now added this detail into my question.

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance.  Your final example does what I want.